# Performance question - what's the best practice to determine if an email already exists in a Mongodb collection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

This is my usual code:

```
const user = await User.findOne({ email });
if (user) {
  return res.status(403).json({ message: "email already exists" });
}
```

While this works, is it the best way to do it?
Is there an alternative?

Again, just a performance question to better understand Mongodb.

Comment: When we come to performance related question, we usually need more context like your current collection schema, existing indexing, your specific query, selectivity of certain field in the query... It would be helpful if you can provide more input.

Comment: if email is a field, create an index on that field, and it will be super fast. each person has different email, so it is expected to have big selectivity also, unless your colleciton have the same emails into many documents. try the index and see